# use "read" command to pass lines as positional parameters to a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, read

The following file runs, but not doing anything, yet it does not error....

```
while read dates; do ./avg_hrly_all_final.sh ${dates}; done < ./dates_all.csv
```

I have a list of dates in "dates_all.csv" that have the following form:

```
2005 01
2005 02
2005 03
```

And the script I am calling "avg_hrly_all_final.sh" works by passing it 2 positional parameters, example:

```
./avg_hrly_all_final.sh 2005 01
```

**FOLLOW-UP**

```
xargs -n2 ./the_script.sh <./dates_to_pass.csv

OR

while read dates; do ./the_script.sh ${dates}; done <./dates_to_pass.csv
```

***work, just make sure the dates of the file being passed is of the same "End of Line" variety as the machine you are running the command on expects ;)***

Comment: As written above, your script should run `./avg_hrly_all_final.sh` with two parameters.  _"no dice"_  So what actually happened when you ran the script?  What made you think that the script's run was not successful?    What error message did you see?

Comment: The script that is supposed to be executed produces a set of files that did not populate. "No dice" is a colloquial term for "it didn't work". No error message.

Comment: If using `zsh`, you need `$=dates` so `$dates` is split into 2 arguments. Other Bourne-like shells should do that implicitly unless you modified `$IFS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a likely job for `xargs`:

```
printf %s\\n '#!/bin/sh' 'printf "<%s>\n" "$$" "$@"' >avg_hourly.sh
chmod +x ./avg_hourly.sh
xargs -n2 ./avg_hourly.sh <<\IN
2005 01
2005 02
2005 03
IN
```

`xargs` will split on the spaces by default and invoke the specified command once per `-n2` occurring arguments. I just wrote a little dummy `avg_hourly.sh` script there which prints its arguments one per line as delimited at either end by `<` and `>` following its PID in the same format. The above prints:

```
<1115>
<2005>
<01>
<1116>
<2005>
<02>
<1117>
<2005>
<03>
```

...just to demonstrate. You should use `<./dates_all.csv` rather than my `<<\IN` here-document as input, though, probably.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel you can do this:

```
parallel --colsep ' ' ./avg_hrly_all_final.sh {1} {2} :::: ./dates_all.csv
```

If the first line of the csv file is the header you can do something like:

```
parallel --header : --colsep ' ' ./avg_hrly_all_final.sh {Year} {Month} :::: ./dates_all.csv
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel